# Can I still have hopes for an offer as a software developer

Tags: interviewing, software-engineering

I attended a bootcamp back in 2017 where I learned Full Stack Development.

I had invested nearly everything I had to learn the skill.
After graduation, I applied to 50+ companies and only had one interview.

Due to low financials I landed a job in a different field that required excessive travel. I enjoyed the job due to the per diem offered and plane rides and getting to really know the country and meet a lot of people from different backgrounds (hardly developers though).

So I put a pause on my software career search for 6 years...

I left the job and started refreshing my memory and I think I'm still very proficient using the basic technologies like HTML, CSS, JavaScript. I understand the whole internet cycle, backend languages like Python, and using frameworks like flask and Django.

I heard about the lay offs happening around these Big Tech companies and noticed a lot were Sr. devs getting laid off. Why would any company want a junior level developer when Sr. devs and a lot of experienced devs are in the market...

I have projects on GitHub and currently working on building some Python games (which I'm having fun doing by the way).

What are my chances getting an offer though?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147138/discussion-on-question-by-a-ozone-can-i-still-have-hopes-for-an-offer-as-a-softw); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 36):

> what are my chances getting an offer though?

Unfortunately, they wouldn't seem to be good.

You don't have a relevant degree. The little formal education you got is 6 years out of date. You have no experience.

For entry level positions, you are competing against degreed candidates with current education, and perhaps an internship for experience.

Your best bet might be to see if you can get interviews for some sort of developer-adjacent role: IT, QA, customer support, project management, etc. The field in which you have been working for the past 6 years may have these roles and may provide a way to leverage some of your experience.

And of course, getting a degree could help.

My first tech job was as a programmer in the IT department of a supermarket chain where I had worked for years. But I had a relevant degree.

You can still get into the field. But you probably need to do more than you have so far.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I get that Im not experienced as a professional. But  what more can I show case experienced for at least as a JuniorDev.  Other than having a personal portfolio website, a login and registration app along with a to-do list app, another app where you can save your favorite books and Memory game. I also know how to implement Dynamic programming, I work almost daily on algorithms. While at the bootcamp, every morning we started with algorithms using data structures like sorting methods and binary search etc.

Comment: I haven't actively applied for the reason that I took along time off. Im just trying to see where the market stands and where I stand in the market now. Which, it looks like need think about somethings lol I was in the Commercial roofing industry, I started off as a surveyor then went off and helped start up a commercial roofing company that is owned by a good friend of mine that needed some assistance managing projects throughout the country and handling some logistics and marketing roles as well.

Comment: With your situation your portfolio should not be the standard “recreate these simple tutorials” portfolio. It should show serious long-term (at least a year) passion projects, work that’s clearly yours (i.e. don’t do the same e-commerce tutorial that everyone seems to do that has the same exact layout and images) and that shows hiring managers that 1) you have knowledge that you can apply, 2) you enjoy the work, 3) you can stick with it, and 4) you write really good code. The typical portfolio won’t help you much because it doesn’t tell the hiring manager much….

Comment: …as most portfolio projects are simplistic and even ambiguous as to whether they’re just direct copies of examples online. So basically stand out and show your stuff—REALLY show your stuff. Which means learning it first. As another answer says, if all you had was a boot camp 6 years ago and you haven’t programmed since, you almost certainly don’t know nearly as much about this as you think (no rudeness intended) and probably aren’t yet at a professional level and have a lot of work to do to 1) get to that point and 2) demonstrate that you’re there. Software dev is hard and very competitive.

Comment: Go for it if you want, but you’ll have to put in the hard work—there are no shortcuts and no one is just going to give you a job.

Comment: It is worth mentioning, that there is a country specific difference here. I am in Switzerland and the company I am working for is doing everything to get developers as the entire country is completely starved for developers except for 2-3 "top" companies. There are specifically programs to get people without IT background through a boot camp and if they show good progress and the team is happy they will be hired.

Comment: Actually one possible route might be to leverage the logistics and managing projects part into a project manager role.  From there you may eventually transfer into a dev.  It more commonly goes the other way (dev to project management), but it does happen in both directions once in a while.

Comment: a bootcamp is not a formal education

Answer (score 19):

I question if you ever had realistic expectations.  You went to a bootcamp.  Let's give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you worked hard and learned the material.  And let's assume the bootcamp actually taught well, taught accurate info, and wasn't just a quasi-scam looking to cash in (most of them are).  That basically means you have 6 weeks to 3 months of training, in whatever the new and shiny tech of the time was (which is no longer new and shiny, and you may or may not understand enough of the foundations to be able to transfer to new tech quickly).  Even right then, you'd have trouble getting a job.  While there's a great deal of need for developers, nobody right out of a bootcamp is anywhere near ready for a real development role.  The whole bootcamp thing was never a great path to a career in software, hiring rates out of them were low and retention in the industry long term was abysmal.  The only thing you're qualified for at that point is a bottom rung, extremely copy and paste role at the bottom of the industry.  Be realistic-  it's trendy to say "degrees aren't needed", but you're competing against people who spent 4 years studying computer science fundamentals (so they may not know the exact tech being used, but have a great deal more understanding of how and more importantly why things work) and a collection of passionate hobbyists who have been self taught and practicing for years.  If you're going to gamble on someone, you're the worst bet of the bunch.

Your best bet was to take the offer you got back then, put a year or two in for experience and then look for the next job with experience on your resume (which means the lack of college would be ignore by many places) and all the knowledge you pick up in 2 years of real world coding.  In that time you could have grown into a bigger role-  I've seen it happen.  Given you didn't do that-  a bootcamp 6 years ago will not impress anyone hiring.  Assuming you don't want to stop your career for college, your best bet is to build a portfolio.  Write some high quality apps that you can show off, put them up on github, and try to leverage that as proof of your ability.  And you're best off doing it to entry level positions in smaller companies and startups-  someone who might be willing to take a risk for a cheap developer.

Now if you want to go that route-  the market isn't hot, but it's not dead either.  The big boys are cutting way back on hiring, but all of that was absorbed by the next tier down and by tangential industries looking at a chance to pick up top tier talent who would normally want to stay in pure tech (banking, engineering firms, media, etc hired heavily).  There's not a huge pool of unemployed super seniors you're competing with.  Even if there was, there's reasons to pick a junior over a senior (you pay them less, they're happier doing boring repetative work that seniors have done hundreds of times, they take direction better if they're part of a team with established leaders, they're less likely to jump when the market heats up, etc).  You just need to prove you're actually capable as a junior-  which right now you have no proof of.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147121/discussion-on-answer-by-gabe-sechan-can-i-still-have-hopes-for-an-offer-as-a-sof); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 8):

7 years is a long time in this industry. Your bootcamp would mostly be classed as irrelevant anywhere with complex needs. You shouldn't target big companies, the smaller ones looking for cheap workers doing fairly mundane tasks are your best bet.

Just keep applying, sooner or later you'll get an offer.

Location also makes a difference. You like travelling and many developing nations wouldn't know a good dev from a bar of soap and would be impressed with your bootcamp cert. I know people who have got senior positions on the strength of a MS cert they got back in Windows 2000 era.

Answer (score 7):

The question you need to answer here is "why should I hire you"?

- Your skills are 6 years out of date; that is a very long time in the software industry.

  - Related to this, "I think I'm still very proficient using the basic technologies" and "I understand the whole internet cycle" are almost certainly not true - if you've never used them professionally, you have an *enormous* amount to learn. Don't take this personally, but you need to be realistic about where your skills are up to.
- You've been working for 6 years, which means either that you're going to want more pay or that you're going to take a big pay cut to get an entry-level developer job. Maybe you're prepared to take that pay cut, but it seems you didn't want an entry-level salary in 2017.

Is there something you *can* bring to the table which all the people finishing a bootcamp this year don't bring? We can't answer that because we don't know your background.

So in summary: is there a chance you'll get an offer? Yes; there's always a chance. Is there a big chance you're get an offer you like? Honestly, no.

Comment: "You've been working for 6 years, which means either that you're going to want more pay or that you're going to take a big pay cut to get an entry-level developer job." There's plenty of jobs that pay less than a junior software engineer.

Comment: A manager may want to hire him because they don't find anybody else. Hiring is still generally strong in the U.S., and the current wave of layoffs will most likely be a temporary dip in the big picture.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where you're located. If you're willing to relocate, I think you might have good chances, even with close to zero experience. I know that in the Netherlands, for example (where working conditions are *a lot* better than in the USA), there is still a shortage of developers.

I even know people in the Netherlands who got traineeships with zero experience.

Your attitude seems self-directed when it comes to deepening your skills, which, to many companies, is pretty important.

Comment: Some context: I've been working as an IT professional in the Netherlands on and off for over 20 years and have occasionally been sitting on the interviewing side of the table. I currently live in Portugal and have noticed that here there's also a shortage of IT workers. The advantage of the Netherlands is that most Dutch IT jobs _don't require any proficiency in the Dutch language_.

Answer (score 3):

I want to be a bit more optimistic. Maybe a large company which looks at formal qualifications and pays an engineer's salary won't hire you, currently.

But a startup or somebody you know personally may. You'll most likely earn less at first, of course, and perhaps work more. The answer to "why would they hire you" is "because you are enthusiastic and cheap and flexible".

You can also try to get freelance projects on the side. You know web technology, and there are many businesses which need a web presence, or need to maintain one. That way you could start building a resume which could help to obtain a steady job later, if you still want one after having tasted the freedom of freelancing ;-).

Comment: +1 for the freelancing suggestion.  Start by doing what you know, get some positive reviews, and progressively switch your profile to what you want to do.

Comment: +1, also consultancies tend to hire a lot of juniors to throw at client projects

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know how common and worldwild it is, but some IT services companies are known to hire non-tech people and retraining them from scratch.  In your situation I’d look for such a company, by definition your career path shouldn’t be an obstacle.

Comment: I was going to advise OP to find a sought-after niche and specialize in that, but this is precisely what these service companies do and they have a better idea of what skills are in demand.

Answer (score 2):

When trying to get employment there are two different parts of the experience that counts:

1. Relevant programming experience
2. Relevant other experience

As others said your programming experience is very dated, so just on that alone I wouldn't count on obtaining an entry level job - most companies would likely pick someone who finished a more recent bootcamp. You can definitely try to brush up your skills and add some fresh projects to your portfolio for you to show to potential employers, but again just on programming experience alone, they might pick someone with a fresh degree.

However in the last six years you did gain other, non-programming skills. Your question didn't really specify what these skills were, but they could be useful in case you find a company specializing in that field needing junior engineers.

For example if you only have a very baseline programming experience, but have worked as a bank teller in the last 6 years, a fintech company might still pick you for a graduate/junior compared to others who have more recent bootcamp experience, as at least you know the domain in which you will work in. Traveled a lot? Maybe a company specializing in travel related solutions (like a holiday booking site) might actually find your experience helpful when deciding who to hire.  There is also a chance that they won't hire you as an Engineer, but invite you to be part of their Product team, from which you might be able to transition in-house to a more Engineering focused role.

Answer (score 2):

First to set expectations, real talk a boot camp six years ago won’t impress a hiring manager, and you’ll have a very hard time getting offers on that basis alone. I wouldn’t count on it myself.

One option is to get a relevant degree if it makes sense for you financially and with your life situation. Another option is to do another boot camp and then apply for an internship somewhere, using the internship as a foot in the door. You might be able to get a job with just a boot camp but honestly it’s not on par with a college degree—there’s a massive gap and an internship is a much easier jump from a boot camp than is a junior position.

Another option is to really get into open source software dev as a hobby, making major contributions to high-visibility community projects over a long period of time (multiple years), and leverage that to apply to a company that does open source dev such as Mozilla.

Or if you’re entrepreneurally minded, starting your own company is always an option, but you’d need to be honest with yourself about the risks (most companies, especially software companies) fail. You’d also need to be honest with yourself about your skill level, studying to fill gaps as needed. Because unless you find someone else to do the coding while you manage, you’ll be doing all the coding, and you’ll be competing with professional coders. So you’ll need to know your stuff.

Bottom line: there are a lot of options. None of them will be easy, but if you want it and are willing to put in the work and keep putting yourself out there, and if you’re strategic and level-heard about it, you can definitely get a job in software dev as long as you have the aptitude and the desire.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an auxiliary occupation such as Software Testing or Quality Assurance (QA).  Many people at my shop apply for these as a "foot in the door".  Each organization has different requirements, but as long as you know and remember the languages, you should be able to get into testing.

You may want to invest some time in refreshing you education and enrolling in some classes.  Many organizations have reimbursement policies.  Thus get your "foot in the door", then take advantage of the education programs.

You may want to try *networking* rather than sending out resumes to random people.  Use a cover letter.  Create copies of your resume that emphasize qualities for your target company.  Find out why they need help.  Use this information when tailoring your resume and cover letter.  Invite someone from your target company to lunch to talk about their career and their company.  Most people like to brag about their history or what they like doing at their company.  This is where you can information about the company's needs (to fill in your resume).   You may want to ask about other people you can talk to, especially hiring managers.